# How does the name "Rugrat" fit with a hairpiece?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

Jordan Belfort introduced his team, who were working
at his company, Stratton Oakmont:

> Jordan Belfort: Smartest of the bunch was Nicky Koskoff. He actually
> went to law school. I called him **Rugrat** because of his piece of shit
> hairpiece.

How does the name "Rugrat" fit with a hairpiece?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [source novel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(book)), Belfort's friend was 'Wigwam', rather than 'Rugrat', so named because his hairpiece looked like a prototypical Native American wigwam.

[image]

> Andy was wearing the typical Stratton uniform—consisting of an immaculate Gilberto suit, white shirt, silk necktie, and, in his case, the worst toupee this side of the Iron Curtain. At this particular moment, **it looked like someone had taken a withered donkey’s tail and slapped it onto his egg-shaped Jewish skull, poured shellac over it, stuck a cereal bowl over the shellac, and then placed a twenty-pound plate of depleted uranium over the cereal bowl and let it sit for a while.** It was for this very reason that Andy’s official Stratton nickname was Wigwam.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Wolf of Wall Street by Jordan Belfort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf_of_Wall_Street_(book))</sup></sub>

The nickname 'Rugrat' (e.g. Because he wore a 'rug' (a hairpiece) that looked like it was rat-like) *may* have been another nickname for Andy (AKA Nicky), but more likely it was an invention for the film. Most of the (real) characters got renamed in the script.

Belfort had a young daughter and she was persistently pestering him to buy him Rugrats marchandise. So he would certainly have been aware of the TV show [*Rugrats*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugrats).

> At this particular moment, Channy and I were standing in the kitchen in Old Brookville, and she was pulling on my jeans and saying, “I want to go to Blockbuster to get the new Rugrats video! You promised!”
>
> In truth, I hadn’t promised anything but that made me respect her even more. After all, my five-year-old daughter was assuming the sale on me—making her case from a position of strength, not weakness. It was 7:30 p.m. “Okay,” I said, “let’s go right now, before Mommy gets home.